# Changing firefox configurations using script

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to make different configuration for Firefox each is programmed in a javascript or in batch file. I want the changes to be effective if I run this script that changes the configuration. 
I wrote the changes I want in a file: user.js which is placed in: 
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxx.default

This user.js file make the changes I want after I restarted my firefox. However, I want to make the configuration changes in dynamic way. i.e. I want to run the js or batch file and the changes become effective. Is this possible.

I found this code that claims to do so:

```
cd /D "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default"
echo user_pref("some.key", "somevalue");>>prefs.js
```

Source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=574905

I copied the code, run the script after placing a key name and value, nothing changed even after restarting the firefox.

Comment: U asked this recently in another post and u were told its no way being used

Comment: With the above script sounds possible. If you have the right to run the script on your machine, you should be able to change any files including the firefox configurations.

Comment: I worked over this about monthes. You were able to do so in older versions but now its removed from ff.